# How to play DVDs which are encrypted (The Lord Of the Rings)

Tags: dvd, decryption

I'm a totally newbie within linux (programs - how to navigate through folders and so on - and commands as well - ...) - but I think linux is very interesting as well.

I have now made a virtually machine with Oracle and have success with my HP printer.

I have tried to find out how to play DVD which are encrypted (I think). Without success I have tried to use 'libdvdread4.2.0' because my thought was that this might be a possible missing.

But honestly - I don't know how to start downloading the right free software for decrypting DVDs in Ubuntu Linux - and to make the install of the software. And I dont know how to search for the right software.

So I will be really glad if someone can help the totally newbie.

My system is Ubuntu "12.04.2 Alternate 64bit Danish".

Answer (score 2):

you have to install a package named as  `libdvdcss2`. open your terminal with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type as

```
sudo apt-get install libdvdread4
```

Then again in the terminal

```
sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh
```

Then restart your system to apply the changes.

[You must read this & credit too](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats/PlayingDVDs)

**Legal Warning:** Check with your local laws to make sure usage of `libdvdcss2` would be legal in your area.

Comment: Thanks for answers - and It seems that a decrypted DVD now can be played. Success and thanks!

Comment: Thanks for answering - but any hints of playing "Lord Of the Rings" ?

Answer (score 1):

You will likely need to `sudo apt-get install libdvdread4` then `sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh` some users will need to restart.

I like using the VLC media player, this may work for you.

Comment: thanks for answers :-) It seems now to work for some DVDs :-)

Comment: But I'm wondering that my "Lord of the rings" cant be played :-( Any hints about it ??